Extrude distorts the texture
Using Blender 2.91. Before somehow with extrusion from a photo everything worked ok.
But now it only squeezes out the walls and the inside remains in place, what am I doing wrong?
could this be because I pulled out the bottom of the photo and made a cover under the house?



In the tool options, you need to enable "Correct Face Attributes" (used to be called "Preserve UVs"):

With this enabled, Blender will try to edit the UVs (and other things like vertex paint if you have some) to adapt them to the modifications.

turned it on but doesn't work! Or do I need to restart the blender after this?

It should work on any new modification. Or is your texture mapped with a different method than UV?

could this be because I pulled out the bottom of the photo and made a cover under the house? added photo above

No. But again, enabling this option will not fix what is already done, it will only make the new extrusions work better.

Understand that this texturing method is very limited, you make shapes that don't exist in the original texture and hope the software can somehow deform the UVs to make it look somewhat seamless, but it can't invent new faces or detail that isn't in the photo.
